# Use DownloadManager to download from an URL accessible through a DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient, download-manager

In my Android app I have to download files from URLs. I use the Android `DownloadManager` but the URLs are accessible only through a `DefaultHttpClient`. Infact these URLs are the result of several `POST` requests. I mean: I'm allowed to download the files only if I'm logged in as user. Could someone help me in managing this situation? I think that it's not possibile to use the DM to download the files by putting directly the link of the requested resource. When I have to download a file there already is an active `DefaultHttpClient` and I'm logged in.
The code I use is the following:

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(client.HttpsGet(url));
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

The HttpsGet is a method of my custom class HttpsClient that does a HTTP GET. In this case I obtain the file encoded in text (like if I open a pdf with notepad). If I directrly put the url of the file (without calling the HttsGet) the devices downloads a blank file.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity...

I solved my problem thanks to this thread: [How do download a file with login using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439296/how-do-download-a-file-with-login-using-httpurlconnection)

But I had to renounce to the DownloadManager

Hope this helps!