# Android DownloadManager with POST method?

Tags: android, download-manager

I started to work with android.app.DownloadManager and faced a problem.
By default, DM sending HTTP GET request to download file:

GET http://www.example.com/getfile HTTP/1.1
Cookie: id=sdfsdf;Max-Age=10800000;Path=/
Host: ___
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: AndroidDownloadManager Paros/3.2.13
Content-length: 0

But I need to send some data in request(e.g. json string)
 
Are there any ways to send **HTTP POST** request in DownloadManager

Comment: if your data is not too important, you can add your data in the get request (while encoding special chars) like this : http://www.example.com/getfile?id=xxx&data=%e9l%e9ment%20encod%e9

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but the requirement is to send data in the body of request.

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for another more accurate answer :

I don't think you can add data to this request since, as you said it, it's a `GET` request and not `POST`.

Maybe this thread can give you a hint on another way to achieve what you want if the `Download-Manager` is not absolutely required : [How do download a file with login using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439296/how-do-download-a-file-with-login-using-httpurlconnection)

Comment: I'am actually dropped this method, and made downloading with AsyncTask. But it's still very wierd, that developers didn't made that simple option to the DM, which, I guess, very commonly used.